# Raising to power in PHP

Tags: php, math, exponent, exponentiation, bcmath

Well, i need to do some calculations in PHP script. And i have one expression that behaves wrong.

```
echo 10^(-.01);
```

Outputs 10

```
echo 1 / (10^(.01));
```

Outputs 0

```
echo bcpow('10', '-0.01') . '<br/>';
```

Outputs 1

```
echo bcdiv('1', bcpow('10', '0.01'));
```

Outputs 1.000....

I'm using `bcscale(100)` for BCMath calculations.

Excel and Wolfram Mathematica give answer ~0,977237.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The caret is the bit-wise [XOR operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) in PHP. You need to use [`pow()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) for integers.

Answer (score 6):

PHP 5.6 finally introduced an innate power operator, notated by a double asterisk (`**`) - not to be confused with `^`, the bitwise XOR operator.

Before 5.6:

```
$power = pow(2, 3);  // 8
```

5.6 and above:

```
$power = 2 ** 3;
```

An assignment operator is also available:

```
$power   = 2 ** 2;
$power **=      2;  // 8
```

Through many discussions and voting, it was decided that the operator would be right-associative (not left) and its operator precedence is above the *bitwise not operator* (`~`).

```
$a = 2 **  3 ** 2;  // 512, not 64 because of right-associativity
$a = 2 ** (3 ** 2); // 512

$b = 5 - 3 ** 3;    // -22 (power calculated before subtraction)
```

Also, for some reason that does not make much sense to me, the power is calculated before the negating *unary operator* (`-`), thus:

```
$b = -2 ** 2;        // -4, same as writing -(2 ** 2) and not 4
```

Comment: This all makes me sad.  The unary operator precedence and the choice of operator, so close to `*` as to be easily typo-ed.

Answer (score 4):

The [`^` operator is the bitwise XOR operator](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). You have to use either [`pow`](http://docs.php.net/pow), [`bcpow`](http://docs.php.net/bcpow) or [`gmp_pow`](http://docs.php.net/gmp_pow):

```
var_dump(pow(10, -0.01));  // float(0.977237220956)
```

Comment: And it seems like gmp_pow accepts only positive powers. Of course, we can convert in to 1/gmp_pow('10', '.01') :)

Answer (score 0):

The [bcpow function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcpow.php#44565) only supports integer exponents. Try using [pow](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2014, and the PHP 5.6 alpha update, there's a much included feature that I hope makes it to the final release of PHP. It's the `**` operator.

So you can do `2 ** 8` will get you `256`. PHP Docs say: "A right associative `**` operator has been added to support exponentiation".