# How to print power series in php

Tags: php

A function with the following signature:
function exponentArr($num) { 
}

Such that when $num = 10, the function returns an array of

[1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024]

Comment: Whats your question? Edit: Are you just copy/pasting your homework or something? Show some effort, you have 1.3k karma, you should know better.

Comment: How are you trying to get 1,2,4,8,16,32...

Comment: @Bulk, Sorry, I have corrected this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Raising to power in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211514/raising-to-power-in-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
function exponentArr($num){
    $arr = array();
    for($i=0;$i <= $num;$i++){
        $arr[$i] = pow(2, $i);
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

This will give you an array `$arr` with the required output.

Comment: it is simply raising 2's power...from 0 to upto `$num`

Comment: `$i < $num` Should be `$i <= $num`

Answer (score -2):

Try this, Working as you mentioned.

```
function powArr($number){
    for($i=0;$i < $number;$i++){
        $array[$i] = pow(2, $i);
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: This is (almost) the same as Moid's answer, except his is correct, more complete and has an explanation. -1.

Answer (score -3):

This is Fibonacci sequence

Try this:

```
$fib = [1,0];
for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++) {
    $next = array_sum($fib);
    array_shift($fib);
    array_push($fib,$next);
    echo $next.", ";
}
```

Comment: No, it's not the Fibonacci sequence. The Fibonacci sequence is 1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34...

Comment: He is not asking for fibonicci