# From CGI formula to PHP

Tags: php, cgi, calculator

I found this formula written in CGI and I would very much like to convert this into PHP.

```
$affordability = $payment / ($monthly_interest / (1 - (1 + $monthly_interest) ** ($minus_terms))) ;
```

Unfortunately, PHP does not recognize the ** symbol, and I am wondering if someone can give me some shed of lights of how to convert this into PHP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Raising to power in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211514/raising-to-power-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the exponential operator.

In PHP you calculate exponents by using the [`pow()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) function:

```
$affordability = $payment / ($monthly_interest / (1 - pow(1 + $monthly_interest, $minus_terms)));
```